# Word square down and across

Tags: word

Use the letters to complete so that;

Three words can be read across, and three words can be read down

[image]

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Did you get this puzzle from somewhere else? If so, please state where you have gotten it from!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

> ```
>  M   E   A   L
>
>  E   C   R   U
>
>  A   R   I   D
>
>  L   U   D   O
> ```

Comment: You beat me to it.